# Providing InjectionToken using another InjectionToken

Tags: angular

I don't understand why the following does not work. If I use a literal string for assigning APP_BASE_HREF it works fine.

**main.ts**

```
 export function main(baseHref: string) {
    platformBrowserDynamic([
        { provide: MY_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseHref },
    ]).bootstrapModule(AppModule);
 }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
export const MY_BASE_HREF = new InjectionToken<string>('BaseHref')

@NgModule({
...
providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: MY_BASE_HREF }],
...
})
```

**Here Is The Important Part of the Console Error**

`Unhandled Promise rejection: url.replace is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: url.replace is not a function
    at _stripIndexHtml (node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js:439)
    at new Location (node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js:278)`

Can I not use an InjectionToken to define another InjectionToken?

Comment: what is your question here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I remember this should do what you want

```
providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useFactory: (url) => url, deps: [MY_BASE_HREF]}],
```

Comment: I'm using InjectionToken, not OpaqueToken. I thought one of the advantages was not having to call `new Inject()`...

Comment: Where did you get that from? Have you tried if it works?

Comment: I got it from this article on [Thoughtram](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/05/23/opaque-tokens-in-angular-2.html#injectiontoken-since-angular-4x). No it does not work, produces the same error in javascript console.

Comment: Beautiful! I'm still a little confused because the documentation states that the generic type argument determines the type of return from the `InjectionToken`. I would expect it to work without having to use a factory.

Comment: If you use `useValue: token` then the value of the token is injected (without even trying to resolve it in any way). If you want it resolved, you can't use `useValue`. I interpret the explanation in the linked article that you can use `new InjectionToken<string>(MY_BASE_HREF)` to specify that the value is of type `string`.

Comment: [Also, notice the generic. It’s the type of what the injector is going to return.](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/05/23/opaque-tokens-in-angular-2.html#injectiontoken-since-angular-4x). If I understand you correctly, I must use the factory in order for the injector to be utilized. If i use a token directly with `useValue:` the injector is not involved at all?

Comment: Exactly, with `useValue` it will just pass that exact value. It's the `deps` that resolves the token.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking how to inject **InjectionToken** inside another **InjectionToken** `factory`.
There is another way as described in [this article](https://netbasal.com/the-hidden-power-of-injectiontoken-factory-functions-in-angular-d42d5575859b).

```
import { InjectionToken, inject } from '@angular/core';

export const ONE = new InjectionToken<string>('ONE', {
    providedIn: 'root',
    factory: () => 'value'
});

export const TWO = new InjectionToken<string>('TWO', {
    providedIn: 'root',
    factory: () => {
        const one = inject(ONE); // this is the injection
        return one + ' received from ONE';
    }
});
```